# IIS 10 error when want to see Configuration Editor for .Net 6.0 project

Tags: .net, iis, .net-6.0, iis-10

I published my .Net 6.0 project and deploy in IIS, when want to open Configuration Editor shows below error

[image]

Comment: Does your web.config file look correct to you? Are you using any special modules? Does the Windows Event Log have any errors? Have you install the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle on this server so that IIS can serve ASP.NET Core sites properly?

Comment: While the symptoms look differently, the actual cause is the same that ASP.NET Core module is missing so IIS configuration system cannot work properly (0x8007000D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should install NET Core Hosting Bundle.

[NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-7.0)